# StarCraft II minimises itself after opening

Tags: macos

Whenever I try to open up StarCraft II, the updating screen appears for a few seconds on 50%. The window then disappears, but it is still shown as open in the dock (light is on under the icon). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: What Mac do you have? Which version of OS X? Open the Console application (in Application/Utilities) and see if something suspect gets written in the logs when this happens.

Comment: Any luck so far on resolving the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried a full re-install of StarCraft? Have you ensured that you have all updates, particularly graphic driver updates, are installed?

Additionally, you can also find several troubleshooting steps at [OS X Daily](http://osxdaily.com/2010/08/03/starcraft-2-mac-problems-crashes-fixes/) which includes a few close descriptions of the issue you described.

Answer (score 0):

I would add this as a comment but I don't have the privilege yet, but I would suggest also asking [here](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/).